# Trying to give too long a name to a dummy chat user for feeds causes an unspecified error

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat, error-message, feed

Today I tried to change [this dummy user’s](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/-431?tab=general) name to *Undergraduate-Education Questions on Math Educators* in accordance with the other dummy chat users posting feeds into Academia’s chatroom. This repeatedly gave me an [unspecified error](https://chat.stackexchange.com/error).

Since seconds before I successfully chaged [this dummy user’s](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/-430/graduate-education-questions-on-math-educators) name to *Graduate-Education Questions on Math Educators,* I guessed that the five additional letters might have something to do with it and tried *Undergrad-Education Questions on Math Educators,* which instantly worked.

I thus suspect that the error was related to the length of the username. A more specific error message would have been helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Display names cannot be longer than 50 characters. There are two ways to deal with it:

1. Error out (basically what you're dealing with now), possibly with a nicer error message, or
2. Truncate the name to the right length.

For now, I've gone with truncation. This will be available with chat build 309. (Right now, our chat product does not display build numbers, so there's no good way to monitor whether things are deployed yet.)